# Writing generic function to take in both Array and ArrayBuffer

Tags: arrays, scala

```
def foo[T <% Ordered[T]](array: Array[T], x: T) = {
      ........
}
```

So with foo I would like it to take in both Array and ArrayBuffer. However when I try and pass an ArrayBuffer, I get a type mistmatch

```
main.scala:67: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]
```

I could simply solve this by making the array parameter an ArrayBuffer instead of an Array but that makes my method less flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scala.collection.mutable.Seq` will allow you to access and modify both `Array` and `ArrayBuffer` by index.

Note: view bound syntax is now deprecated, you can achieve the same thing with an implicit parameter:

```
def foo[T](array: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[T], x: T)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]) = {
if (ordering.gt(array(0), x)) {
  array.update(0, x)
}
```

}

You can find more info about that in SI-7629 (https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629)

Hope that helps,

Thanks

Comment: The implicit parameter you used is not equivalent to the view bound.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
def foo[T <% Ordered[T]](seq: Seq[T], x: T) = ???
```

`ArrayBuffer` is indeed an implementation of `Seq`, and `Array` has an implicit conversion to it, so it will work just fine.